# Can square be an answer to the condition satisfying for rhombus and satisfying for square only in a particular case?

Tags: geometry

> The diagonal of a parallelogram PQRS are along the line $x+3y=4$ and $6x-2y=7$ . Then which geometrical figure (square, rhombus, rectangle, a cyclic quadrilateral) is PQRS?

I know the slopes are perpendicular, so the diagonals are perpendicular.

I got the same question in my exam and it was under the section of multiple options correct questions. Ideally, the answer should be square, rhombus and cyclic quadrilateral. But, we can argue by saying that the condition for rhombus will always satisfy for any parallelogram while condition for square and cyclic quadrilateral will satisfy only for specific parallelogram.

So the answer should be marked as square, parallelogram and rhombus or only rhombus.

Comment: The parallelogram **must** be a rhombus, it **can** be a specific rhombus, namely a square, in which case it is also a rectangle and a cyclic quadrilateral. So depending on the problem poser's intention, either only rhombus is correct or all answers are correct ...

Comment: I am sorry. There wasn't a should in it. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't think rectangle can ever be correct as its diagonals aren't perpendicular.

Comment: @AdityaJain They are if it's a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A special case of parallelogram (sides unequal)is the rhombus (when sides are equal). A special case of rhombus is a square (when diagonals are also equal).

A special case of parallelogram (oblique) is the rectangle (when angles  are all  equal to $90^{\circ}.)$ A special case of rectangle is a square. (when sides are equal).

The square is a special case of cyclic quadrilaterals when sides are all equal. Then each angle becomes equal to $90^{\circ}$.